# Order of html title attribute

Tags: feature-request, tags

Anyone else find it a bit weird that tags are placed first in the html title attribute. for example I've seen quite a few start:

> 6 - Some question here
>
> 7 - Another question here

When I have a load of tabs open gathering resources on my macbook I often see tabs with just 6/7 then a few more random tags in them which isn't very helpful.

Can the tags be appended to the title instead of prepended?

Comment: No idea why someone would vote this down, it was a legitimate question...

Comment: On meta sites down-votes mean somebody disagrees with what implied in the question; in this case, somebody disagrees with the necessity of appending the tags to the title, instead of prepending them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [SEO purposes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions/71925#71925), the Stack Exchange engine adds in the most used tag on the question that hasn't already been organically worked into the title. This makes sense for many use cases, and is an automated substitute for "In X, How do I...?"

For example, let's say on Stack Overflow your question was about sorting arrays in PHP. You might title your question *How do I sort this array?* and tag it [php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php). The question, on Google's SERP, might then appear as *php - How do I sort this array?* which is more useful, when you're looking for PHP solutions.

Note that you aren't the only one to find it weird and this isn't a Drupal Answers specific problem. See https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2266/allow-tags-to-be-blacklisted-specifically-from-appearing-in-the-html-page-title, a question opened on a different meta site.

Comment: I certainly think we are losing out on using drupal 6/7 as a tag in this case.